# Why doesn't Calcium Carbonate Burn?

Tags: home-experiment

I was doing my Science Fair Project and I tried to burn Calcium Carbonate. But the match went out as soon as it touched the Carbonate. I am wondering why the Carbonate isn't burning. I later tried to use a torch and a lighter but nothing worked. My science fair project is due tomorrow and I've looked everywhere on the internet but nothing really explained why the calcium carbonate didn't ignite. 
Do I need HEAT or something like that to make it burn?
(I'm a 5th grader so please take it easy on me)

Comment: What reaction? Why would it burn?

Comment: The only reaction you will get by heating calcium carbonate is decomposition to calcium oxide and carbon dioxide.

Comment: HEET? You mean the anti-freeze/water-removal thingy?

Comment: @paracetamol nahh, its most probably HEAT. (probably misspelt in the hurry to submit question)

Comment: @Pritt The OP *does* mention previous attempts to set the thing on fire (such as, use of a torch, lighter,etc). Ultimately ending the question by asking if "HEAT" is necessary to do the trick seems... *highly* unusual.

Comment: @paracetamol Adding anti-freeze to help combustion? Quite unlikely.

Comment: @Pritt There're quite a few anti-freeze agents out there that are *highly* flammable ._.

Comment: @paracetamol like ethylene glycol right? I think that one is quite flammable.

Comment: Do you mean combustion of calcium carbonate?

Answer (score 4):

Calcium Carbonate cannot burn. Its already in its highest oxidation state (+2 for Calcium and +4 for Carbon), and cannot be oxidized (combusted) to a higher oxidation state. However, calcium carbonate does *decompose* on heating to quicklime and carbon dioxide.

$$\ce{CaCO3 -> CaO + CO2}$$

This doesnt give out any flames in the first place.

Now let's talk about how to salvage your project. Why don't you try to heat the calcium carbonate, and show that carbon dioxide is evolved by using a burning match stick, or by using lime water? $\ce{CO2}$ extinguishes the burning flames and forms a milky precipitate with $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ (limewater). This can be used to show that perhaps egg-shells and marble have carbonate content in them.

Comment: *Why don't you try to heat the calcium carbonate...* The kid's a fifth-grader, not sure if he can get his hands on the 800+ degrees Celsius crucible for his project ;)

Comment: @paracetamol Since the kid doesn't have access to the "800°C crucible", another alternative could be to boil at lower temperatures with strong acids. $$\ce{CaCO3 + CHA -> CaA2 + H2CO3}$$ and the carbonic acid that forms will anyway equilibrise to carbon dioxide and water. $$\ce{H2CO3 <=> CO2 + H2O}$$.